# Using parent class method and child instance, call the most concrete method (child's method)

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, methods, dynamic-programming

Consider this code:

```
class Interface():
    def my_method(self, a):
        print(f"Interface: {a=}")

class ChildA(Interface):
    def my_method(self, a):
        print(f"ChildA test: {a=}")

method = Interface.my_method
my_instance = ChildA()

method(my_instance, a=4)
```

This prints `Interface: a=42`. How can I make it print `ChildA: a=42`?

Obviously I do not want to use ChildA.my_method, I want a solution that works for any new child classes that are implemented in the future.

Comment: You would normally write this as `my_instance.my_method(4)`.  If you want the method name to be a parameter, `getattr(my_instance, 'my_method')(4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is just write a helper function:

```
def methodcaller(name):
    def inner(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(obj, name)(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

method = methodcaller('my_method')
```

Knowing the method name and the fact that the object will be an instance of `Interface` doesn't let you perform any part of the method resolution in advance, unfortunately. You would need to know the concrete class in advance. (Also, `operator.methodcaller` doesn't work, because it requires all method arguments to be provided at methodcaller creation time.)